# Add m_1'th multiple of one line to the m_2'th multiple of another line.

Tags: gauss

How can I use the gauss package to indicate that the  m_1'th multiple of one line is added to the m_2'th multiple of another line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gauss}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gmatrix}[p]
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\rowops
\add[\cdot (-7)]{1}{2} % Should be -4 times the second line plus 4 times the third, "+" in the middle of the line
\end{gmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second optional argument to `\add`, but you also have to modify the command `\rowaddtolabel` as described in section 1.3 of the manual (well, the description is quite terse). Here's an example where the behavior is the same as the standard one if the second optional argument is not used; if it is given, it is typeset below the +.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gauss}

\renewcommand{\rowaddtolabel}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \scriptscriptstyle +%
  \else
    \scriptstyle\overset{+}{#1}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gmatrix}[p]
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\rowops
\add[\cdot(-4)]{1}{2}
\end{gmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{gmatrix}[p]
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\rowops
\add[\cdot(-4)][\cdot 4]{1}{2}
\end{gmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this also be done in a symmetric way, i.e. that the + symbol is in the middle of the vertical line.

Comment: @student The labels are attached to the corners, I'm afraid one has to do much more work on the internals of `gauss` for that.

Comment: I just had a look on the source code of gauss. Indeed, it seems to be hard coded. Even though I didn't really understand it, I had the feeling that it might be possible to just add another label in the middle of the line by redefining one or two commands from the source code. Another option might be to calculate the length of the vertical line in some way and just shift the + (which will remain bound to the corner) by the half of that length upwards.